# How to properly use feature transformation functions in Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Suppose I want to use `ft_max_abs_scaler` on every column of a dataset. This is what's in the documentation:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
iris_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, iris, name = "iris_tbl", overwrite = TRUE)

features <- c("Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width", "Petal_Length", "Petal_Width")

iris_tbl <- iris_tbl %>%
  ft_vector_assembler(input_col = features,
                      output_col = "features_temp") %>%
  ft_max_abs_scaler(input_col = "features_temp",
                     output_col = "features")
```

Note that `ft_vector_assembler` creates a new column `features_temp` and `ft_max_abs_scaler` creates another new column `features`. Now suppose I want to break down the vector into individual columns, I have to do this:

```
iris_tbl <- iris_tbl %>% sdf_separate_column("features", into = features) 
# result in error because column name cannot be the same
```

Since there is no good way to delete columns, I wonder if there is a better way to do feature transformations with Sparklyr without keeping creating new columns.

Comment: Sigh... The thing is - `sdf_separate_column` is kind of a definition of a very-bad-idea. While it looks great on a toy examples, I just doesn't take into account specifics of the underlying system, and just doesn't scale and if you want to integrate this with other `o.a.s.ml` tools, it is completely useless. Also you can drop columns (with `transmute(...)` or `select(-to_drop)` for example).

Answer (score -1):

```
iris_tbl <- iris_tbl %>%
              ft_vector_assembler(input_cols = c("Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width", "Petal_Length", "Petal_Width"), output_col = "features") 
iris_tbl <- iris_tbl %>% 
              sdf_separate_column("features", into = "new") 
iris_tbl
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could explain your answer, rather than just supplying code. It's not clear why you think this is a good approach to the problem.